# Remove phrases from string

Tags: php, email-address

I have a string like this:

`..., "test1@test1.com" <test1@test1.com>, "test2@test2.com" <test2@test2.com>, "test3@test3.com", "test4@test4.com" <test4@test4.com>, ....`

I am exploding everything by `,` , but problem is that i dont want to have value laike this 
`[0] => "test1@test1.com" <test1@test1.com>` i need to remove the emails which are in those `<..>` brackets.

So the result should be like this `[0] => test1@test1.com`. 
Any offers how to drop the second phrase?

Comment: Please look for existing questions. This or something very similar should have been asked and answered already. You might be looking for: http://php.net/imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist

Comment: Be aware that the part inside the quotation mark is free-text, it may be the name of the recipient or something else. To get an email address you should use the parts within the brackets, not the part within the quotation marks. (e.g. `"Peter Peng" <peter.peng@example.com>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = '"test1@test1.com" <test1@test1.com>';
$str= preg_replace("(<.*>+)", "", $str);
print $str;
?>
```

Comment: Actually according to your question this is not what you want. Care to elaborate?

Comment: And if it was, please accept the answer that answered exactly so earlier than this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19045743/367456 - that is normally considered more fair.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of a function that has been especially tailored for such email address lists, for example [`imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist`](http://php.net/imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist). Mapping it and extracting the information you need might do it already:

```
$list     = ""test1@test1.com" <test1@test1.com>, "test2@test2.com" <test2@test2.com>, "test3@test3.com", "test4@test4.com" <test4@test4.com>";
$adresses = array_map(function($entry) {
    return sprintf('%s@%s', $val->mailbox, $val->host);
}, imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist($list, ""));
```

This has the benefit that it properly deals with the quoted printable text in front that you have - which done properly is non-trivial (really).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way here - use strip_tags function (see [strip_tags description](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php))

Comment: Why the upvotes? This answer is *plain wrong*. I wonder why nobody sees? Blended by the light? @Ilya: Yes, please, see the strip_tags description your own. Read it. Compare with the question. Quick shot in the wrong direction I'd say, worth some DVs honestly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Regular Expressions to replace anything between <...> for empty strings, then explode your modified string into an array.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `preg_match`:

```
preg_match('(<.*>+)', $your_emails, $matches);

print_r($matches); // array of zero or more matches depending on input
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explode your text into an array and the run a `array_map` with a function that cleans your text. Something like this:

```
function clean($t){
    //Use regexp to replace desired text
    return preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $t);
}    

$text = '"test1@test1.com" <test1@test1.com>, "test2@test2.com" <test2@test2.com>, "test3@test3.com", "test4@test4.com" <test4@test4.com>';
$a = explode(',', $text);
var_dump($a);


$b = array_map("clean", $a);
var_dump($b);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a line of code:

```
array_map(function($a){ return trim($a, ' "'); }, explode(',', strip_tags($string)));
```

And the whole:

```
<?php
$string = <<<TK
"test1@test1.com" <test1@test1.com>, "test2@test2.com" <test2@test2.com>, "test3@test3.com", "test4@test4.com" <test4@test4.com>
TK;
$result = array_map(
            function($a){
                return trim($a, ' "');
            },
            explode(',', strip_tags($string))
    );
var_dump($result);
```

**Output:**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "test1@test1.com"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "test2@test2.com"
  [2]=>
  string(15) "test3@test3.com"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "test4@test4.com"
}
```

Comment: According to the question, it's looking for the email addresses without the quotes around. In your output there are quotes around.

Comment: No problems with a quotes tags i did this for removing it : `$str = str_replace('"', "", $str);`

Comment: @hakre `trim` is specially made for this kind of use as its name clarifies its job, simpler and more readable. so if I was going to use `sscanf`, I preferred `preg_replace` more.

Comment: trim has less control on which characters to match. Also you don't want to replace / filter but just to extract as the information exists verbatim, you only need to locate it. I would do filtering only if the first is not possible due to unlcear constraints which are not the case here. `preg_match` / `preg_replace` ship with more options but these options are not needed here, simpler regular expressions like those of `sscanf` already make it. These are merely the reasons why I suggested it.

Comment: @hakre what do you mean by saying `trim` has less control! It's just about removing `quotations` and `spaces`. also we don't want to extract! but we want to manipulate already extracted data and what `sscanf` actually does is filtering like preg_replace, how ever more strict and dirtier.

Comment: @revo: For example: How many spaces and quotes? You can't say (and you normally don't want to when using trim (just those *around*). However if you know how many you actually want to remove (e.g. one quote before and a quote plus one space after) you can not control that exactly, e.g. it would remove any quotes and spaces around, regardless in which order and in which count. Trim does not allow you to control that behavior precisely. More clear?

Comment: And if you're looking for a very fine method, check preg_match and preg_split but you need to be able to write regular expressions well. Then you can do that in one call (if you're willing to ignore [RFC822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822)).

Comment: @hakre your last but one comment is definitely correct but coding will differ from case to case. Saying that, at OP case there is no need for more complexity than trimming. Neither preg_ functions nor sscanf. But different solutions, as always, are welcome.

Comment: Yes sure, it was meant to discuss things not that there is only the one right way. Just wanted to tell you why I suggested that so it's more clear to you to make your own decisions not that you should decide the same way.

Answer (score -1):

if

```
$yourString='"test1@test1.com" <test1@test1.com>';
```

you can use:

```
$yourString=substr($yourString,1,strpos($yourString,'<')-3);
```

(edited)